# Android ActionBar Icons not showing

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

i am totaly frustrated ,every thing is setup right and even in rendering (using Android Studio) the action bar icons are displayed but when i run it on a physical smartphone (pocket neo 4.1.2) it shows nothing but ic-launcher and title whats the solution ?

activity_main_actions.xml

`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Search Widget -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_b"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
    <!-- Location Found -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location_found"
        android:title="@string/action_new"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

`

main_activity.xml
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

`
MainActivity.java

`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);


        actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Hide the action bar title


        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


}
```

`

Comment: You are setting it programatically to ic_launcher what do you expect? actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

Comment: i mean the other icons

Comment: Is it the ic_action_b and ic_action_location_found?

Comment: yes, those two icons are not displayed thats the problem

Comment: change your activity from activity to actionbaractivity.

Comment: changed it ,nothing solved

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved !

it was my mistake that i added support:appcompact-v7 with a minsdk = 14 ,
thank you anyways for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

OK from what I check in [here](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_pocket_neo_s5310-5391.php) your phone resolution is really small (240 x 320)
So because you are using `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` it will only show if there is room in the actionbar.
If you want it to always be shown you need to change it to `app:showAsAction="always"`

Hope this can help you, if you have any other question related to my answer feel free to ask in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, if the target device is not v21 (lollipop) you should use the `android` namespace, instead of the `app` namespace when defining `showAsAction`.

If you want compatibility for both, and your IDE is complaining about the `android` namespace, make a new layout with the `app` namespace and put it in your v21 layout folder.